# Testing the input if it is numeric or not

Tags: c

I wrote a C program wherein I am accepting a numeric input from the user. However, if the user inputs a character, then I have to show that it is an invalid input and make the user enter a number again. How do I achieve this? I am writing the program using gcc compiler in Ubuntu. The search results on Google suggest to use `isalpha` function...however, it is not available in the libraries I guess.

I also tried the below...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main()
{
    system("clear");
    if (isdigit(1))
        printf("this is an alphabet\n");
    else
        printf("this is not an alphabet\n");
}
```

Comment: Post your program, show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Note that `isdigit()` checks for digits, not alphabetic characters.  The value `1` is distinct from `'1'`; the latter is a digit according to `isdigit()` but the former is not. The value `1` is equivalent to control-A which is a control character, not a digit. Note that on Unix systems, `void main()` is unconditionally wrong.  You're allowed to use `void main()` on Windows as a Microsoft extension.

Comment: You should look into the different format specifiers for `scanf`, checking whether or not something is a number will be pretty simple if you use the correct one, assuming you are planning on using `scanf`.

Comment: Your program does not accept any input from the user.

Comment: `isalpha` *is available* from `<ctype.h>`

Comment: Well...I tried using isdigit() and it worked as below...Is there any other way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `scanf` to get user input with `%d` as you want to scan an integer. In your case, `scanf` will return 1 on sucessfull scanning.

```
int num;
//loop to prompt use to enter valid input
while(scanf("%d",&num)==0) //scanning an integer failed
{
    printf("invalid input ! Try again\n");
    scanf("%*s"); //remove the invalid data from stdin
}
```

The functions `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` works when you are getting a character input using `%c` in the `scanf`. If you want to scan input using `%c` , then you can simply check like what you have done in your code provided that you get input using `%c`. Note that character 1 (`'1'`) is note equal to integer 1 . Characters have their integer values as represented by [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). Your program to prompt the user again when the user enters anything other that a number using `%c` will look like this:

```
    char ch;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter a number\n");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);

        printf(Your input is %c\n",ch);
        if(isdigit(ch))
        {
            printf("This is a number\n");
            break;
        }
       else
           printf("This is not a number. Invalid input\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code which worked fine..using isdigit()

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void main()
{
    system("clear");
    char str[1];

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%s",str);

    printf("What you entered was %s\n",str);
    if(isdigit(str[0]))
        printf("this is not an alphabet\n");
    else
        printf("this is an alphabet\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    bool check=true;

    while(check)
    {
    if( (c>='a'&& c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z'))
       {
           printf("%c is an alphabet.",c);
           check=true;
           break;
       }
    else
    {
       printf("%c is not an alphabet.",c);
        check=false;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own. It's better to check digits since there're less cases for digits.

```
bool isDigit(char c) {
    bool rtn = false;
    switch(c) {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            rtn = true;
            break;
        default:
            rtn = false;
            break;
    }
return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Why not `return c >= '0' && c <= '9';`

Comment: Yeah. That's even better.